# C#3.5 MVC2 routing skip optional param

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

Here I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "test", // Route name
    "DataWarehouse/Distribution/{category}/{serialNo}",
    new { controller = "DataWarehouse", 
          action = "Distribution", 
          category= UrlParameter.Optional, 
          serialNo = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Category and serialNo are both optional params.  When the routing is like: `DataWarehouse/Distribution/123`, it always treat 123 as the value for category.

My question is how I can make it to know the 1st param could be either category or serialNo, i.e. `DataWarehouse/Distribution/{category}` and `DataWarehouse/Distribution/{serialNo}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DataWarehouse/Distribution/{category}/{serialNo}
```

Only the last parameter can be optional. In this example category cannot be optional for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what your parameters will look like you can add a [route constraint](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx) to differentiate both routes

Ex if your serial are 1234-1234-1234 and your category are not like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "serialonly", // Route name
    "DataWarehouse/Distribution/{serialNo}",
    new { controller = "DataWarehouse", 
          action = "Distribution", 
          category= UrlParameter.Optional, 
          serialNo = UrlParameter.Optional },
    new{serialNo = @"\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}"} 
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "test", // Route name
    "DataWarehouse/Distribution/{category}/{serialNo}",
    new { controller = "DataWarehouse", 
          action = "Distribution", 
          category= UrlParameter.Optional, 
          serialNo = UrlParameter.Optional },
    ,
    new{serialNo = @"\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}"}  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, i was trying to route based on data (`{year}/{month}/{day}`) where `month` or `day` could be optional. What I found was that I couldn't do it with a single route. So I solved it by using 3 routes, from generic to specific (year, year and month, year and month and day). I am not completely pleased with it, but it works.

So provided that you are looking for `DataWarehouse/Distribution/{category}` and `DataWarehouse/Distribution/{category}/{serialNo}` routes, i think this would work for you.