# Redirecting to action preserves routing parameter invalid on new action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, routes

Here are my routes:

```
_routes = RouteTable.Routes;

_routes.Clear();

_routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
_routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon = @"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});

_routes.MapRoute(
    "Message-specific Actions",
    "Messages/{message}/{action}",
    new {controller = "Messages", action = "ViewMessage"},
    new {message = @"\d+"}
    );

_routes.MapRoute(
    "General Message Actions",
    "Messages/{action}",
    new {controller = "Messages", action = "Index"},
    new {action = @"\D+"}
    );

_routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = ""} // Parameter defaults
    );

_routes.MapRoute(
    "Catch All",
    "{*path}",
    new {controller = "Error", action = "Error"}
    );
```

Here's the relevant parts of my controller:

```
public class MessagesController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: ~/Messages/1
    public ActionResult ViewMessage(int message)
    {
        return View(// stuff to get message from repo);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    // POST : ~/Messages/1/Delete
    public ActionResult Delete(int message)
    {
        // do stuff
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Problem is, the URL in the browser after the redirect in `Delete` is not `~/Messages/` as I would expect, but instead it's (assuming `message` was, say, 12) `~/Messages/12/Index`.

Index doesn't even accept a `message` parameter. I don't understand why this is happening. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following rule

```
_routes.MapRoute(
    "Message-specific Actions",
    "Messages/{message}/{action}",
    new {controller = "Messages", action = "ViewMessage"},
    new {message = @"\d+"}
    );
```

to

```
_routes.MapRoute(
    "Message-specific Actions",
    "Messages/{action}/{message}",
    new {controller = "Messages", action = "ViewMessage"},
    new {message = @"\d+"}
    );
```

It works.

while writing rules, you should know that only the last parameter can be optional and the mandatory parameter should be placed before. Replacing this does not match rule(the modified one), although it should. I have no exact reason, but when you passed the 1st(Messages[implicitly) and 3rd parameter[action], it tried to match {message} too, which is not logical. so the rule is place mandatory params in the beginning as discussed in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187456/c3-5-mvc2-routing-skip-optional-param) too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to switch the order of your 'Message-specific Actions' route and 'General Message Actions'

Comment: This doesn't help, as it causes the URL for the `ViewMessage` route to become `/Messages/ViewMessage?message=12` instead of the desired `/Messages/12`.